# jquery scroll block page from scroll

Tags: jquery

I have created scroll function to scroll down element with 100vh height. 
So function scroll down only when user scroll down... but after animation finish i can't even scroll down or top...

What i missing??

```js
var position = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var div_hei = $("#scroll").height();
  var div_hei = div_hei * 0.8;
  var page_scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (page_scroll_top < div_hei) {
    if (page_scroll_top > position) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scroll2").offset().top
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
  position = page_scroll_top;
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#scroll2 {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll">Div that schould be scrolled</div>
<div id="scroll2">Div next to scrolled element</div>
```

As you can see on code , when we scroll down Page are blocked from scroll...
When we refresh page we still can go up to the top of page, and scroll down to animate again.. and the page were block again..

what i missing?

Comment: you need scroll up function.

Comment: ye so how to add function that will set height of window to scroll window? it should not pass value for if statement if scroll pass div height

Comment: How your code will understand user is scrolling down or up ? else part is required for case   if (page_scroll_top < div_hei)

Comment: if (page_scroll_top < div_hei)  means if user is inside scrolled div... next part if (page_scroll_top > position) means if user scrolls down... so if both condition aren't meat page wont scroll and that correct... but when we make scroll page stop...

Comment: Your scroll animation is causing a loop inside the event listener, you should differentiate between the user and the animation causing the scrolling. Try `$('html, body').not(':animated').animate({`.

Comment: no it's not that. That wont work. the problem is window scroll function, when i change it on on clicl event, everythig working correcly...

Comment: as @shikkediel rightly said its causing the loop. just check this example you will understand it is going into loop https://jsfiddle.net/ar9t6uwh/

Comment: The animation fires the `scroll` event (many times a second) which in turn triggers the event listener - causing the animation to get initiated over and over again. That is the loop I mentioned. Obviously when the event listener is not listening to `scroll` this won't happen. You can see [here (on the right)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqZeJP) that the animation gets queued dozens of times. Once they're all finished, you can scroll the page again.

Comment: Here with the approach I suggested - resulting in one animation only: [codepen.io/anon/pen/RdyzZw](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RdyzZw). That doesn't actually break the loop though but it does prevent the undesired effect. I would go about it slightly differently as a solution - check at the beginning of the event listener if the animation is already taking place and then exit directly when that is the case.

Comment: For the purpose of demonstration, here's a version that counts down the animations that are in progress: [codepen.io/anon/pen/MxGMdq](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxGMdq). When it gets to zero, scrolling is possible again.